# Wrong execution order in Azure Data Factory Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

The pipeline is called from a main pipeline. But for some reason that I do not understand the execution is starting in the second component (notebook) and is skipping the first one (lookUp) that is used to update a status throught a simple query.

What could be happening?

[image]

Comment: have you published all the changes, seems to me a generic browser or cache issue.

Comment: Yes I have. Several times. Eventually I had to move the look up from the pipeline.

Comment: Can you post your steps as an answer, and You can then [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 0):

If you have published all the changes to the pipeline and yet see this issue, I can only imagine it to be a generic issue related to browser or cache.

I am able to repro this multiple time without any issue or find it executing as you described.

[image]

Maybe if you could share what you have configured in lookup (datastore type..etc.), we can try understand this scenario.

Comment: Yes, It was the first time that I saw that. I published the solution but at the end it was necessary to locate the lookup in another position.

Comment: oh, by "another position" you mean to reorder or just move it in the canvas of the same pipeline?

Comment: No, inside the main pipeline. It was necessary to change some parameters variables, but it worked.